# Numpy: get index of smallest value based on conditions

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array as such:

```
array([[ 10, -1],
       [ 3,  1],
       [ 5, -1],
       [ 7,  1]])
```

What I want is to get the index of row with the smallest value in the first column and -1 in the second.

So basically, `np.argmin()` with a condition for the second column to be equal to -1 (or any other value for that matter).

In my example, I would like to get `2` which is the index of `[ 5, -1]`.

I'm pretty sure there's a simple way, but I can't find it.

Comment: you could prefilter your array like `np.argmin([i for i in a if i[1] == -1])` but it still returns one as it works on the array `[[ 10, -1], [ 5, -1]]`

Comment: Yeah, I have tried these approaches. What I need is the index of the initial array, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [10, -1],
    [ 3,  1],
    [ 5, -1],
    [ 7,  1]])

mask = (a[:, 1] == -1)

arg = np.argmin(a[mask][:, 0])
result = np.arange(a.shape[0])[mask][arg]
print result
```

Answer (score 2):

```
np.argwhere(a[:,1] == -1)[np.argmin(a[a[:, 1] == -1, 0])]
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but if I try `np.argwhere(d[:,1] == 1)[np.argmin(d[d[:, 1] == 1])]` instead (changed from -1 to 1), I get a wrong result.

Comment: I think you'd need to select the appropriate column, e.g. something like `np.argwhere(a[:,1] == -1)[np.argmin(a[a[:, 1] == -1,0])]` (untested).

Comment: Yeah, i missed column selection in argmin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not efficient but if you have a relatively small array and want a one-line solution:

```
>>> a = np.array([[ 10, -1],
...               [ 3,  1],
...               [ 5, -1],
...               [ 7,  1]])
>>> [i for i in np.argsort(a[:, 0]) if a[i, 1] == -1][0]
2
```